# Search system not searching both name and surname

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a search system which helps you filter people list
My Table (People)

```
id | name | surname | email
```

There is a textbox which you can enter the name, surname or email so the list is filtered as you type.

It finds the records if I write only name or only surname. But if I  enter name and surname it does show nothing.

I have tried Mysql's CONCAT function. But it did not work.

My query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM People 
WHERE name LIKE :p1 
    OR surname LIKE :p2 
    OR email LIKE :p3
```

I have tried this

```
SELECT * 
FROM People 
WHERE name LIKE :p1 
    OR surname LIKE :p2 
    OR email LIKE :p3 
    OR CONCAT(name, char(32), surname) LIKE :p4
```

and this

```
SELECT id, 
    name, 
    surname, 
    CONCAT(name, char(32), surname) AS fullname 
FROM People 
WHERE name LIKE :p1 
    OR surname LIKE :p2 
    OR email LIKE :p3 
    OR fullname LIKE :p4
```

How can I obtain the system that can find results when name + [space] + surname is entered?

Comment: What kind of indexes are there? If you have a `SPATIAL` index, you can try `MATCH()...AGAINST()` clause as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can split the keywords and search for each individual keyword (or expression) in your columns (name, surname and email).